# Molecular Script Add-on: Why does this simple particle system blow up?

Tags: particles

This particle system with Molecular Add-on blows up even though there seems to be more than enough space between the particles. Any idea why is this happening? I'm using Blender v2.81.16.

Here is the file
[image]

Frame 1:

[image: frame 1]

Frame 2:

[image]

Particle System rendering settings:

[image]

Comment: Can you add your particle system setting? I just get the baked animation, but unless I can reproduce it, I can't fix it

Comment: Have you tried the attached .blend file?

Comment: is your object a collision object?

Comment: @user1566515 Yes of couse

Comment: @WhatAMesh Do you need any additional info?

Comment: @J Block It doesn't have any Physics properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Issue comes from particles **self collision** (so boundaries).
In your case if you Display as Circles, you can see they are overlapping, set Render size to 0.02. Particles stops to explode.

---

- To see particle's collision boundaries switch ***Viewport display*** > *Display as Rendered* to ***Circle***.
- Adjust *Size* value, so circles doesn't overlap.
- The **same value set in *Render** > Render as Object > Scale* panel.
- Then you can switch back *Display* > *Display as Rendered*.
- Scale object (Sphere) in 3Dview (Object or Edit mode) to desired size.

---

**What matters** - *Render Scale* (viewport size is only for reference)

**What confuse** - *Object Scale* in 3D view does not affect self collision

The goal is to keep not overlapped "Display as Circles" with the same value for "Render as Object" ... Than if you scale object (Sphere) in 3Dview via Object mode or Edit mode doesn't matter. A size of object doesn't matter here, object can overlap each other or be a micro, its size doesn't affect behaviour of particles.

Render Scale 0.05
[image]

Render Scale 0.1
[image]
[image]

[image]

To see real boundary with *Rendered as Object* - add a new *Sphere* (by default *Scale* 1 / *Dimension* 2) and set Render Scale to 0.02, same set for selected Sphere in 3Dview Properties > Item > Transform > Scale. To see it right, uncheck in *Particles Properties > Render > Object >  **Object Scale***. Now you can change only Render Scale value and have a control over real boundary at the same time (don't change Scale in 3D view from now).

[image]
[image]

Note: ***Object Scale*** means - use object scale value **on top of particle scale**. If particle will be size 2 and object scale 0.5 rendered particle (*Sphere*) will be size 1, but size of collision boundary stay 2. And "Render Scale" value matters :)

Comment: Thank you for shedding some light on this unnecessarily confusing situation :) In your answer, when you say " Render size" do you mean " Render > scale"? I'm not sure if it's different for different versions, but as of v2.81, there's no " Render size".

Comment: So the bottom line is that Molecular Script uses one and only one setting to calculate collisions between particles and that is Render>Scale value which it treats simply as particle size. Correct?