# Emitted Particles clustering and intersecting

Tags: animation, particles, path

I hope you can help me :D

I am trying to create a blood vessel. I have set up a particle system with an animated collision object to kill the particles and get them pumped out in intervals.

Now my problem is, the particles are following a path (point method), but they all are very close and not really distributed and even worse, they intersect each other.

Any ideas how to solve this? Maybe even with the help geometry nodes? Any reply is most welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: It might be helpful https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/166866/2214

Comment: Thanks, will check it out!