Fix Particles not intersect with each other Non overlapping
I have to create a scene with some particles, but I encounter difficulties...
The particles are intersecting each other.
I have attached here the .blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Oq7iXtxP0skwezAeAp35UBQaVBzRYGO6/view?usp=sharing


particles are always intersecting. They are no rigid bodies. That's normal default behaviour. If you wanna have particles, which can collide with each other, you can try the free molecular add-on.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/166866/2214
